# TinyMCE popup windows not working in Django development server

Tags: python, django, tinymce, django-tinymce

TinyMCE is working just fine, all except for the popup windows. They come up blank, and after a little bit of Google searching, apparently it has something to do with cross domain errors with Firefox and Django. I tried using document.domain, but I have a feeling that it doesn't work when you're using the Django development server (http://127.0.0.1:8000).

Comment: I have no problem with tinyMCE popups and Django's dev server. Try Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) to see if there happens anything suspicious during the request.

Comment: What is your `MEDIA_URL` set to?

Comment: MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/m/'

with the http:// before localhost.

Comment: try using a relative link for `MEDIA_URL`, eg `MEDIA_URL = '/m/'`. Using firebug (or the log from the dev server) to examine the request is also a good idea.

Comment: I looked at the request via Firebug. It says that there is an Illegal document.domain error. The document.domain for my dev server is http://127.0.0.1:8000, which I don't see why that would be a problem. Firebug also says that tinyMCEPopup is undefined. All the file permissions on all of the tinyMCE folders are on chmod 777, so I'm assuming that there is no problem accessing the js files required for the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 127.0.0.1:8000, if I use localhost:8000, everything seems to work perfectly. I'm not sure why. Maybe it's because localhost:8000 is a domain and 127.0.0.1:800 is not.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with 127.0.0.1 as a domain. The problem is that it's different to your media domain `localhost`, although they both point to the same thing.

TinyMCE doesn't like different domains for the media, which is why having a relative `MEDIA_URL` would work. Using the URL `http://localhost:8000/` to access your server would also work, because the domain would be the same as the `MEDIA_URL`, so too would setting your `MEDIA_URL` to `127.0.0.1:8000/m/` and accessing it with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.